# How to make a diamond shape with the Polygon in pygames graphics library

Tags: python, graphics, pygame

I can't figure out how the [polygon](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.polygon) function orders the points and the docs aren't helping so I can't make the required Diamond Shape.

Answer (score 2):

Imagine you would plot the points in a coordinate system on a sheet of paper and immediately connect them with a line one after the other. So the first point would be connected to the second, the second to the third, etc., and the last to the first. Finally, the resulting shape is filled with the desired color.

```
import pygame as pg


pg.init()
screen = pg.display.set_mode((640, 480))
clock = pg.time.Clock()
BG_COLOR = pg.Color('gray12')
BLUE = pg.Color('dodgerblue')
points = [(200, 200), (250, 250), (200, 300), (150, 250)]

done = False
while not done:
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            done = True

    screen.fill(BG_COLOR)
    pg.draw.polygon(screen, BLUE, points)
    pg.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)
```

Answer (score 1):

`Pygame.draw.polygon` is a function which you can use to connect several points together and draw them as a shape.

This gives flexibility in the shapes you can draw. If the shape you have in mind does not have a function somewhere in `pygame.draw` or `pygame.gfxdraw`, then you can create it yourself using this function.

Let's take the diamond you want to draw as an example.

First of all, you may be able to just draw a square and rotate it around it's center 45°,
but since you want to draw it using the `polygon` function ( which is probably neater ), here is an example of that below

NOTE: The points used for this are calculated as follows:

- *First of all define a **width** and a **height***:

  ```
  diamondWidth = 80
  diamondHeight = 100
  ```
- ***Point 1 and 3*** (top and bottom point of the diamond):

  Point 1 can be any point on the screen. You can think of this as the position of the diamond, if you like.

  I want the diamond to be at the center, so I'll define it as follows:

  ```
  pos1 = (screenWidth/2, screenHeight/2 - diamondHeight/2)
  ```

  As for Point 3, it is the bottom point of the diamond. This means it has the same X, but a greater y value (specifically, larger than Point 1's y value by `diamondHeight`). That should be easy

  ```
  pos3 = (pos1[0], pos1[1]+diamondHeight)
  ```
- ***Point 2 and 4*** (left and right points of the diamond):

  Either one of Point 2 and 4 has to be the right, the other has to be the left point of the diamond. Let's say Point 2 is the left point. It can then be defined as follows:

  ```
  pos2 = (pos1[0] - diamondWidth/2, pos1[1] + diamondHeight/2)
  ```

  Point 4 will simply be the other side, which means it has the same Y value but is either lesser or greater then Point 2's Y value by `diamondWidth`. In my case, since Point 2 is the point to the left, and Point 4 is more to the right, so Point 4 will be *greater* than Point 2 by `diamondWidth`.

  ```
  pos4 = (pos2[0]+diamondWidth, pos2[1])
  ```

Now that we defined the points of the diamond, we can use the `pygame.draw.polygon` function to connect them and draw the shape.

---

### Side note

You mention you're confused about the function, so here is an overview of the parameters:

1. Surface: The screen, image, or whatever other `pygame.Surface` instance to draw the shape on. In most cases this will be the screen you define at the top of your code.
2. color: The color used to draw the polygon. For simpleness, this is an `rgb` value. `rgba` values (add transparency / translucency) can take effect if the `pygame.Surface` instance you passed in the first parameter received a `pygame.SRCALPHA` flag, like this:
   `pygame.Surface((width, height), pygame.SRCALPHA)`
3. pointlist: A list (maybe tuple) of points to connect. These are in the order they are connected in. I.E: The first point in the list is connected to the second, the second to the third, the third to the fourth, and so on.
   Also the last point is connected to the first in order to complete the shape (other wise it would be an open shape, it's last side not connected)
4. width: The final (optional) argument. Sometimes not passed, as it
   defaults to 0.

   - If the value is 0: The shape is filled with the color parameter    passed before.
   - If the shape > 0: Only an outline of the shape is drawn, and the shape is not filled in. The thickness of the line is the the value
     you pass.

I hope that clears things up. Please follow up for any queries

---

So here is an example of using the polygon function. I only included the main loop and some of the setup to shorten the length of this. If you remove the comments and some of the setup code (probably replace it with your own), then this becomes a very short and simple program:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

screenWidth = 600
screenHeight = 600

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((screenWidth, screenHeight))
pygame.display.set_caption("Diamond")

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
MAXFPS = 30

# define the diamond points as described above
diamondWidth = 80
diamondHeight = 100

pos1 = (screenWidth/2, screenHeight/2 - diamondHeight/2)
pos2 = (pos1[0] - diamondWidth/2, pos1[1] + diamondHeight/2)
pos3 = (pos1[0], pos1[1]+diamondHeight)
pos4 = (pos2[0]+diamondWidth, pos2[1])

# points for the first diamond
points = [pos1, pos2, pos3, pos4]

# points for the second diamond, which are exactly like the first except their
# Y value is incremented over the original points so it does not appear over
# it, but rather to it's left
secondPoints = [(p[0]+diamondWidth+10, p[1]) for p in points]

stop = False
while not stop:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            stop = True

    window.fill((255, 255, 255))

    # DRAWING THE DIAMOND:
    # Here is where we connect all the points in the [points] array, and
    # draw them as a shape with a certain color (used cian because it's
    # a diamond-dy color lol)

    # Draw filled diamond
    pygame.draw.polygon(window, (0, 255, 255), points, 0)

    # Draw empty diamond with lines of thickness 4
    pygame.draw.polygon(window, (0, 255, 255), secondPoints , 4)

    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(MAXFPS)

pygame.quit()
```